# Is polynomial hashing function efficient?

Tags: performance, data-structures, hash, hashtable, hashcode

I am wondering that why there is no talk about the efficiency (in terms of time and space) of polynomial hashing function? The recommended value of constant in my book is 33,37,39 and 41, but they fairly big numbers. If my string is lets say 15 a's (aaaaaaaa..) then computing (41^15)*(97)+(41^14)*(97)+...... (97 because its ASCII value of a) is such a heavy task and if I million entries then you can imagine. So please can anybody answer my two questions?

1. Am I mistaken about the time and space complexity of this function or my understanding of it is correct?
2. If I am right then why do we need to use it? can we find some other better more efficient alternative?

Comment: That's just a multiplication and an addition per item, no big deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's implemented like this:

```
int h=0;
foreach (character c in string)
{
    h = (h*41)+c;
}
return h;
```

As you can see, it takes no significant space and is quite fast.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is beautiful!